# Merge 500+ TIFFS into one (ArcGIS 10.4.1)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.4

I have over 500 TIFF images with the same projection. I need to combine all these files into one large file. From there I need to perform several clips of certain areas of interest.

I can do the clip part fine but I need to combine these 500 TIFFS into one large image. I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1.

I saw multiple methods of doing this and was wondering which is the most efficient. Mosaic data set, raster catalogs I am not really sure or which is outdated.

Comment: I've found the fastest way to merge tiff data is with Erdas Imagine's Mosaic Pro. Otherwise, I use Mosaic to New Raster in ArcGIS, which is notably slower.

Comment: There are enough imponderables to make this question opinion-based. Given that you want to clip a subset, I can't help wonder why you don’t mosaic just the parts required, then clip from there. If you really need help on this you need to show more work, and provide more details as to the sizes and alignment of the component images. If you need a single image at the end, neither a catalog nor a mosaic dataset would be an end of the processing -- only a mosaic will do. There are other questions which address efficiency in mosaicking.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176554/processing-time-speed-for-mosaic-to-new-raster

Comment: Vince I would love to select the rasters that i need to merge but i cant find a way to do that. All the files are named numerically and i cant select 50ish rasters in arcmap. Or haven't found a way to select the rasters i need then merge those specifically. (Select feature)

Comment: I agree with Aaron ! You would be better off with that Erdas Mosaic Pro..

Comment: What were the "multiple methods of doing this" that you saw?  Please always provide links to your earlier research so potential answerers know where you are up to in trying to answer your own question.

Comment: Add them all to a mosaic data set which will output one file if I'm correct but it wasn't the most efficient way. And something about a raster catalog. Merging these files will take 3-4 days on the machine I'm running so I'm trying to pick the most efficient way. If i can select feature to the rasters i want that would be best

Comment: Sorry poly I'm on a mobile at the moment and don't have access to the links but they were official ESRI docs

Comment: With ArcGIS the most efficient way is building mosaic dataset first (not mosaic into new raster !!!). Above dataset works as a single raster if needed and it is very fast to build. (I am working with thousands of tiled aerial images)

Comment: @FelixIP thanks i want to keep this in arcgis. Can u elaborate on your comment not into new raster

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-mosaic-dataset.htm  Avoid buiilding overviews (!) if you are using it for clips etc

Answer (score 1):

May be off topic because it is not a direct ArcGis solution:

For an simple routine you could use the GDAL tools [gdal_merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) in conjuction with [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to **merge and cut** the geo-tiffs on a data level (geotiff for example).

You will need python as well as gdal. You could install [osgeo4w](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) for windows, to get both tools in one step.

The "best-how-to-aspect" depends on the location and extention of the image cut's in the tile set you want to proceed. In a worst case it will have a fractal nature. A wild mix between many small footprints on the image borders at one side versus one big footprint overlapping many image tiles.

At least you could use a common resampling approach:

1. calculate and sort the image cuts vs. the tiles that are involved and store them in a list.

   ```
    cut  minx miny maxx maxy tiles 
     1    10   10   2100 4200  (1,2,3,4) 
     2    310  310  2100 4200  (1,2,3,4) 
    ...
   ```
2. resort the list and create an list of unique merge tasks

   ```
   tiles      cuts 
    (1,2,3,4)  (1,2)
   ```
3. merge the tiles and procced the cut  for 
   each corresponding cut-image (pseudo code)

   ```
   tiles = readTile(tileList)
   cuts  = readCuts(cutList)
   foreach tile in tiles:
       proceed("gdal_merge.py -o temp_file file1, files2, file3, file 4")
       foreach cut in cuts.getID():
          id, minx, miny, maxx, maxy = cuts.getExtentFromCutList(cut)
          proceed("gdal_translate -o cut-id  -projwin minx maxy maxx miny temp_file"
   ```